# netsuite multiple inventory locations not displaying when using nlapiSearchRecord

Tags: javascript, netsuite, inventory

How would you go about getting all inventory locations for a particular item? What I would like is to check if a specific inventory location has any allotted inventory for an item.

I have tried to use the nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filter,columns) to try this but it only returns the preferred location and not all locations even though their is inventory in the other locations.

Filters were setup as such:

```
filters = [ new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid',null,'is',10)];
```

If I add `new nlobjSearchFilter('location',null,'is',34)` to the filters which is the id for the inventory location I am looking for, I don't get any results at all.

the return I get from the above filters only list the preferred location and not any other locations with available inventory.

-- UPDATE --

After updating the code to use the suggestion below I am now getting the inventory location but not the correct inventory count for the location which should be 5 not 87

```
var itemId = 3376;
var locationId = 34;

var items = [];
var filters = [];
var columns = [];

filters = [
            new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid',null,'is',itemId),
            new nlobjSearchFilter('inventorylocation',null,'is',locationId),
            new nlobjSearchFilter('quantityavailable',null,'greaterthan',0)
        ];

columns = [
           new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid'),
           new nlobjSearchColumn('inventorylocation'),
           new nlobjSearchColumn('quantityavailable'),
           new nlobjSearchColumn('quantityonhand'),
        ];


var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filters,columns);

if (results != null)
{
    for (var i=0, l=results.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        var result = results[i];

        items.push(result);
    } 
}
```

OUT PUT printed in JSON Format

```
{ 
   "id": "3376", 
   "recordtype": "assemblyitem", 
   "columns": { 
      "itemid": "Marketing : Misc : T-Shirt Womens Medium", 
      "inventorylocation": { 
                      "name": "InventoryLocation", 
                      "internalid": "34" 
       }, 
    "quantityavailable": 87, 
    "quantityonhand": 90 
   } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. NS development would be impossible without SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the field to use is the 'inventorylocation' field.

Comment: thanks that looks like its getting me closer to where I want to be.

Comment: Well it seems that gives me the location but not the actual inventory count for the selected location. Basically I get the total allotted amount for all inventory for that particular item and not just the inventory count for that location. Back to the drawing board I go. Thanks for the help though it does give me some insight.

Basically I have a total count available for of 87 and only 5 of those are actually from the local that I am looking at...

Comment: Have you tried using 'locationquantityonhand'?  That might give you the quantity on hand for a specific inventory location.

Comment: That did it thank you very much I will flag your answer as the correct one. Do you happen to know any online resources that has search columns listed out or am I just screwed in using the not so  great Netsuite documentation? Thanks again.

Comment: Its hard to copy links from the NetSuite help but you can try searching NS help for 'records browser'.

Comment: What's the difference between the locationquantityavailable and quantityavailable fields here: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/item.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `locationquantityavailable` and `locationquantityonhand` columns instead of the ones you are using.

For references to the available columns/fields on a records, you may lookup the "Records Browser" in Help.

Comment: What's the difference between the locationquantityavailable and quantityavailable fields here: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/item.html ?